# Rich-text input (not textarea) plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, richtext

There are plenty of rich-text editors out there, but I'd just like to add some bold, italic, and underline capabilities to a one-line text input. Are there any plugins already available for this? (preferably jQuery, but any work)

Comment: It's worth noting that, as far as I know, the rich-text editors work by loading an iFrame in place of a text area, whose content is set to the control's initial value; the DOM is then switched to edit/design mode, and then the javascript plugin typically plugs into that.  The most obvious thing to do is to customise one of those editors' height (and key bindings to prevent new lines being added).

Comment: @Andras That was the backup. I'd just like to avoid doing extra work. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: in tiny_mce, for example, you could disallow `<div>`, `<p>` `<br />` `<ul>` (for example), thus restricting the user to edit only a single printed line of html.  That said, whether that will actually stop new lines appearing while they edit is another matter (those nodes might get stripped when the HTML is saved back from the iFrame to the textbox rather than as the DOM is manipulated).

Comment: Text input fields cannot style the text with bold, italic, or underline. The best you can do is create bbcode-like wrappers. Otherwise, use a rich text editor.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Googling gave me these guys:

- A light weight RTE jQuery Plugin:
  http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html
- markItUp! universal markup jQuery editor:
  http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/
- WYSIWYG jQuery Plugin:
  https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg

They all are quite basic but powerful and you can adjust its size to almost one line.

EDIT: Otherwise use bbcodes as j08691 stated.